# Ubuntu 18.04 kill LAN network when hanging

Tags: networking, server, kernel

I have a weird incident that happened from time to time like this. A machine sometimes just stops responding, and then kills the LAN network. If I unplug it, then the LAN is working fine again. I tracked down syslog before the moment the incident happened, and saw a bunch of this, but I googled, and they seemed to be minor.

Could you please point me to where to dig? Copied below is the log, it happened on 00:35 am, and then died until 08:02 am, when I unplug the machine.

My system log:

```
Oct 3 00:35:55 MY-MACHINE kernel: [20719.879824] vethea172e4: renamed from eth0 
Oct 3 00:35:55 MY-MACHINE kernel: [20719.954772] br-37cd44a6d6a2: port 1(veth6b0d7ee) entered disabled state 
Oct 3 00:35:55 MY-MACHINE systemd-udevd[13045]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable. 
Oct 3 00:35:55 MY-MACHINE NetworkManager[1256]: [1664732155.0888] manager: (vethea172e4): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4815) 
Oct 3 00:35:55 MY-MACHINE avahi-daemon[1168]: Interface veth6b0d7ee.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS. 
Oct 3 00:35:55 MY-MACHINE avahi-daemon[1168]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface veth6b0d7ee.IPv6 with address fe80::782f:2cff:fe27:f135. 
Oct 3 00:35:55 MY-MACHINE kernel: [20719.962138] br-37cd44a6d6a2: port 1(veth6b0d7ee) entered disabled state 
Oct 3 00:35:55 MY-MACHINE kernel: [20719.963252] device veth6b0d7ee left promiscuous mode 
Oct 3 00:35:55 MY-MACHINE kernel: [20719.963253] br-37cd44a6d6a2: port 1(veth6b0d7ee) entered disabled state 
Oct 3 00:35:55 MY-MACHINE avahi-daemon[1168]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::782f:2cff:fe27:f135 on veth6b0d7ee. 
Oct 3 00:35:55 MY-MACHINE systemd-udevd[13045]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable. 
Oct 3 00:35:55 MY-MACHINE NetworkManager[1256]: [1664732155.1209] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/vethea172e4, iface: vethea172e4) 
Oct 3 00:35:55 MY-MACHINE NetworkManager[1256]: [1664732155.1209] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/vethea172e4, iface: vethea172e4): no ifupdown configuration found. 
Oct 3 00:35:55 MY-MACHINE systemd-udevd[13045]: link_config: could not get ethtool features for vethea172e4 
Oct 3 00:35:55 MY-MACHINE systemd-udevd[13045]: Could not set offload features of vethea172e4: No such device 
Oct 3 00:35:55 MY-MACHINE NetworkManager[1256]: [1664732155.1224] device (veth6b0d7ee): released from master device br-37cd44a6d6a2 
Oct 3 00:35:55 MY-MACHINE NetworkManager[1256]: [1664732155.1228] devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/veth6b0d7ee, iface: veth6b0d7ee) 
Oct 3 00:35:55 MY-MACHINE gnome-shell[2069]: Removing a network device that was not added 
Oct 3 00:35:55 MY-MACHINE gnome-shell[2069]: Removing a network device that was not added 
Oct 3 00:35:55 MY-MACHINE NetworkManager[1256]: [1664732155.1239] devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/vethea172e4, iface: vethea172e4) 
Oct 3 08:02:52 MY-MACHINE systemd-modules-load[369]: Inserted module 'lp' 
Oct 3 08:02:52 MY-MACHINE systemd-modules-load[369]: Inserted module 'ppdev' 
Oct 3 08:02:52 MY-MACHINE systemd-modules-load[369]: Inserted module 'parport_pc' 
Oct 3 08:02:52 MY-MACHINE keyboard-setup.sh[352]: cannot open file /run/tmpkbd.MHTeaJ 
Oct 3 08:02:52 MY-MACHINE systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage... 
Oct 3 08:02:52 MY-MACHINE systemd[1]: Started udev Kernel Device Manager.
```